# Add Argument to existing Json String

Tags: json, servlets, arguments, gson

I have this situation:

More servlets set the httpservletResponse `content-type to json/application`.

I output my json this way:

```
 out.write (new Gson().toJson(myObject));
```

where myObject, is an object and the code above provides creating a string json like using myObject structure.

Now I need to add an argument on the top of the json, because I need an argument like: "result":"okay".

Is there a way to add this without changinc myObject class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Instead of building a `String` using `Gson#toJson()` use `Gson#toJsonTree()` which parses the object but creates a JSON internal representation using `JsonElement` subclasses. You will need to cast it to a `JsonObject`, then add the new property and finally write it to the output stream.

Code example:

```
package net.sargue.gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class SO36837061 {
  public static class MyClass {
    int a = 1;
    String b = "salut";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) new Gson().toJsonTree(myObject);
    jsonObject.addProperty("result", "okay");
    String json = new Gson().toJson(jsonObject);
    System.out.println("json = " + json);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
json = {"a":1,"b":"salut","result":"okay"}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks! I resolved in another way, but this code is what I needed, and I will use soon. Thanks!